# Unity3D: Run-time generated AnimationClips leaking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I currently create AnimationClips dynamically while my game is running to move some pieces around. You can see what I mean here: https://youtu.be/u1My9JX4K-c?t=8s , when the pieces get grouped together and then open again. I cannot reuse the clip because the pieces will have a different position next time, so all the movements need to be changed.

Right now, I create a new clip whenever I need them to be grouped and separated, and attempt to replace any existing clip with this:

```
private void ReplaceAndPlay(AnimationClip clip, string name) {
     var old = Anim.GetClip(name);
     if (old != null) {
         Anim.RemoveClip(name);
         Destroy(old);
     }
     Anim.AddClip(clip, name);
     Anim.Play(name);
 }
```

(Anim just points to the gameObject's Animation component)

But using the profiler, I see that the animation clips just keep accumulating, they don't seem to be garbage collected. Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Can they be garbage collected?

Comment: Do you need animation clips to do this? Can't you just change the rotation using a [lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html)

Comment: It just makes it cleaner than implementing it by hand in Update, and I can reuse my animation generating functions for other things. So I would prefer to use an animation and solve the leaking problem.